# Latest news using Sphinx

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx for indexing news which i gather from about 100 sites daily.

Each news document has id,title,body,date fields.

For homepage of my project i want to show latest news of today group by topic.
For example site A has a news with title:

```
"Internet of Things Will Burn Privacy for a While, Cerf Warns"
```

And site B has one with title:

```
"Cerf Warns : Internet of Things Will Burn Privacy for a While"
```

I want to show these news as one item with sites that covered it. Like:

```
"Internet of Things Will Burn Privacy for a While, Cerf Warns"
Published by : a.com,b.org,...
```

Is it possible with Sphinx?

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx wont do it on its own. It can't just 'magically' group similar items into clusters of likely duplicate items.

(if the titles where identical - charactor for charactor, could just group by, but thats not the case in your example)

Once you've got your documents into clusters - eg assigned them a 'cluster-id'. Eg the two items in your example, would have the same cluster-id. A unique article not mentioned by mulitple sources would have its own id. - Sphinx could then help you search or render results - using the built in group by.

---

So first you need to cluster your documents.

There are dedicated tools for this type of thing, for example: https://github.com/open-city/dedupe

But a very basic one could actully be built with sphinx. Would probably work ok in your example, because the titles contain the same words, just in different order.

Basically just need a script that loops though all documents that DONT have a cluster-id, then run a sphinx search against the index, looking for duplicates. If one is found, duplicate its cluster-id, otherwise just allocate a fresh unique id.

This script can then just be run after inserting news documents, to 'cluster' any new stories.

The exact sphinx query can be varied. eg just including the words in a basic query, would require all the same words - regardless of order. But could also perhaps use a quorum search to require most words matching etc.

Might also want to filter by date to avoid dupluicating stories from wildly differnt dates.

Comment: Do you think it's better to specify keywords of every article before indexing with sphinx? @barryhunter

Comment: Almost definitely maybe. Dont have enough info to know.